# Creating a dynamic RegExp pattern to include a variable value

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

I have a RegExp that I would like to make dynamic and create in a string. I want to change this:

```
var result:Object = value.match(/John\/(.*?) /);
```

to this:

```
var firstName:String = "John";
var result:Object = value.match(firstName + "\/(.*?) "); // this doesn't work
```

I'm using ActionScript but I think what would work in JavaScript would work as well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you can create a new instance of the [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class:

```
var firstName:String = "John";
var result:Object = value.match(new RegExp(firstName + "\/(.*?) "));
```

When you use `value.match(firstName + "\/(.*?) ");` the first parameter to the match function is a string, but it [should be a regular expression object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).